# jQuery.ajax() image data from php are not displayed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple login form with ajax and I want to display the users name and picture
to a `<div>`.

The username is shown but the picture not.

```
     $.ajax({

         type: 'POST',
         url: baseURL,
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
             action: "LOGIN",
             username: username,
             password: password
         },
         success: function(data) {
             if (data == "empty") {
                 $("#errorArea").fadeIn();
                 $("#errorArea").html("Error: Wrong username or password");

             }
             else {
                 $("#userPanelContent").html(data);
             }
         }
     });
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: The HTML that's being returned from `baseURL` is the important part here. From your tags, I assume there's PHP code that generates that HTML.

Comment: base url holds a path to the php file. I solved it was apath issue. I fixed firebug helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a relative path issue.

Make sure that any relative paths in the returned HTML are relative to the page you're loading into, or just use absolute paths.

Comment: The picture path is set into the database i just get the picture path through php query and giv it to a variable.
Then when i acces that variable the img is not shown

Comment: You still probably have a relative path issue.  What do you see in Firebug?

Comment: Oh man thanks i forgot firebug... That helped me alot .. and u where right it is a path issue... Thanks again firebug it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are saying your returning dataType is json. so you need to return json. but what you want is just return a string.. so remove your line `dataType: "json"` and it should work.

If you dont want to remove you dataType line, you need to do something like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => true));
```

then in your succcess function you can do this:"

```
success: function(data) { 
    if (data.status) { 
        $("#errorArea").fadeIn(); 
        $("#errorArea").html("Error: Wrong username or password");
    }else {
        $("#userPanelContent").html(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: When i control for username and password in database i set the echo "" if there is no row found. thats why i wrote this
 if (data == "empty") {
                 $("#errorArea").fadeIn();
                 $("#errorArea").html("Error: Wrong username or password");

             }
             else {
                 $("#userPanelContent").html(data);
             }
so if data is empty it means no rows found and thats wrong username and password. The firebug helped. It was a path issue. some stupid mistakes i made into php. Thanks again